# Taxonomy term custom menus

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I have a site with different sections for separate projects.  Some of the sections are just a single page with a project summary, but others are more involved with several pages.  All the pages are created via a content type "projects."  I have a term reference field in the content type in order to categorize which pages belong to which project.

What I'm trying to do is have a menu automatically generate for all the pages that belong to a specific project.  I've found ways to create menus of terms, but I can't find a way to make a menu of nodes using the term.

Any ideas?
-JB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should create a view which display only the nodes related to the current term. You'll have to play a bit with contextual arguments but it works. The simple way is to add a contextual argument to the term field.

Answer (score 0):

i think I have the a similar goal.

For exemple I would have 2 differents **content type** "**Story**" and "**tutorial**" each of them have the **common tag "potatoes"**.

I would like a **menu item** that **link to a view** that will display **all the stories about potatoes** and another to **all the tutorial about potatoes**.

I was thinking of using views for that but there is no "**display format: Menu Item**" so i'm stuck.

help please